# How can I build a template engine with Intellisense?

Tags: c#, .net, templates

I want to build a declarative templating engine like Razor or T4, but with a robust editing experience, especially including Intellisense.

Really, I'd like to use Razor or T4, and not reinvent any wheels. But Razor tooling only seems to exist within an ASP.NET project, so you can't just add a cshtml file to an arbitrary project and get Intellisense. And T4 doesn't seem to have Intellisense at all, and can't be scripted outside of VS, which is quite limiting.

So I want to be able to write a file like:

```
{{some way to set the model type}}
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  {{code for c in Model.ClassNames}}
  public partial class {{c.TypeName}}
  {
    ...
  }
  {{endcode}}
}
```

and when I'm within a {{code block}} the  editor knows this and gives c# Intellisense, perhaps by merging the blocks and analyzing with Roslyn. Then, another process can parse the template, matched with a model, to emit the template output.

Or is there a better way to think about this whole problem?

Comment: *"Razor tooling only seems to exist within an ASP.NET project"* - It's just a library. It's not easy to use, but it can be used without ASP.NET [Core], and there are NuGet packages that simplify things to varying degrees. I used one to generate both plain text and HTML e-mail bodies with Razor templates in a Windows Service a few years ago.

Comment: @madreflection: But can you use it within, say, a WPF project, by making a cshtml file, where the modeltype is a type in the same assembly, and have Visual Studio give Razor tooling for that file? I've never found a way to accomplish this.

Comment: The Razor portion of it isn't dependent on the guts of ASP.NET [Core]. As long as you're careful about your dependencies, yes, you should be able to use it in a WPF project. My .cshtml files were embedded resources in a Windows Service, and the model classes were defined in that same assembly.  No ASP.NET-anything involved. And yes, the Razor tooling worked as it normally did.

Comment: Search nuget.org for packages with "razor" in the name.  The Microsoft.* packages can be used directly, and it'll take you some time to figure out how, or you can skip those and investigate one of the third-party libraries. Try them out and see what works best for you.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use it for generating classes, like your post has, though. Using it for plain text e-mail bodies was challenging, and I had to use `@Html.Raw()` too much for my taste. My main point was that Razor isn't as integrated with ASP.NET as you seemed to think it was.

Comment: @madreflection: Indeed, my needs are general purpose, including things like code generation in plain text, and I'm not sure Razor is well suited. It just has really good tooling, so it'd be nice if it worked. That said, I can't get Intellisense to work on a Razor file in a project that isn't a web project.